# Is there any alternative to add an app in SharePoint team site without adding to App Catalog site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts, app-catalog

I have SharePoint Team Site Administrator-level permission. I don't have App Catalog site permission and I don't have SharePoint Administrator-level permission. So, I can not create a site-level App Catalog.

I need to add the custom SPFx app and add that app to the SharePoint Team Site. My user is in the Owner group of that team site.

Is there any alternative to adding an app to my site without adding the App Catalog site collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can deploy SPFx solutions without using App catalog.

You have to two types of App catalog sites in SharePoint:

1. Tenant level app catalog - Deploy & use solution for all site collections
2. Site collection app catalog - Deploy & use solution for single site collection

You can request your SharePoint tenant administrators to create site collection app catalog if you don't have enough permissions. This is one time activity only.

After app catalog creation, you as a site collection administrator can deploy SharePoint Framework solutions that will be available only in that particular site collection.

**Related documentation**: [Use the site collection app catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.